# open all files without an extension - Python

Tags: python, directory

Hello I'm trying to write a script to open all files without an extension in a folder organised in subfolders etc.

I've failed at finding a way to declare all files without a certain known type (there are some PNGs and txt but I'd like to understand how to generalise this approach)

Folder hierarchy:

```
main
-sub
--file1
--file2.txt
-sub2
--file1
--file2.png
```

Etc (obviously the files aren't the same in the different folders)

Example of a said file:
`1.2.840.113619.2.227.20792477682.2116111104093220.75`

Comment: Why not just check if filename contains a `'.'`?

Comment: forgot to add it, the files contains points, I'll modify the question with a real example

Comment: In that case can create a list of known file extensions and then check every filename against this list using `filename.split('.')[-1]`

Comment: That was something I thought of but wanted to check if there would have been a way to dodge making a manual list of known extensions, thanks for the tip in though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be rather general approach for the folder structure you provided:

```
import os

base_pth = 'path/to/you/main'  # e.g. 'C:\my\main'
known_extensions = ['.txt', '.png']

for base, dirs, _ in os.walk(base_pth):
    for d in dirs:
        for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(base, d)):
            pth = os.path.join(base, d, f)
            if os.path.isfile(pth) and os.path.splitext(f)[1] not in known_extensions:
                with open(pth, 'rb') as file:
                    # do your thing
```

Comment: Thank you man this helped me out :)
didn't help dodging the .DS_Store files (osx) but I managed to delete them in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

[os.path.splitext(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

> Split the pathname path into a pair (root, ext) such that root + ext == path, and ext is empty or begins with a period and contains at most one period. Leading periods on the basename are ignored; splitext('.cshrc') returns ('.cshrc', '').

With that you can get the extension and than you can do `if ext == ""` to get the files without extension.

Comment: Edited on the go but an example of a said file is:

1.2.840.113619.2.227.20792477682.2116111104093220.75

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['png', 'jpg', 'avi']

filename = '1.2.840.113619.2.227.20792477682.2116111104093220.75'
print(filename.split('.')[-1])

if any(i for i in lst if i == filename.split('.')[-1]):
    print('known extension')
else:
    print('Unknown extension')
```

Try this code inside your script. You can add other known file extensions to the list. Can find all known extensions list online if you need it.